# I'm tired of waiting so long for junit test

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Spring Boot always loads full components in the container when I try to run a junit test everytime.It takes more than 2 minutes to run,and that wastes me a lot of time.So,how can I avoid this?

Comment: Don't use a spring boot test annotation? THey are for loading up a slice or the full application context. For Unit tests you should not require spring to be involved to verify the functionality

Answer (score 0):

You could and should avoid using Spring Dependency Injection in unit test, otherwise is more like an integration test then a real unit test.

You could manually instantiate your under test classes (via constructor) and mock their dependencies.
A cool library like [mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) can help you with mocks.